# Simplify writing a date

Tags: javascript, date, discord.js

I would like to simplify the display of a date (2016-06-26 05:23:55) which on discord.js gives this:

```
Sun Jun 26 2016 05:23:55 GMT + 0200 (Central European Daylight Time)
```

**I would like to have this : Saturday June 26, 2016 at 05:23**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest using a library such as date-fns to format the date.

have a look at their docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format

You don't have to, but you'll have to it manually (array of months, pick Xth month, ...)